# Calculating a field value based on PK in Django

Tags: python, django, model, primary-key

Goal: Set `customer_number` to a calculated value of `b_country` + `id` + 10000.

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_number = models.CharField("Customer #", max_length=10, default=0)
    b_country = models.TextField("Country", max_length=2, choices=COUNTRY_OPTIONS)

    @property
    def get_customer_number(self):
        a = self.b_country
        b = (self.id + 10000)
        return a + str(b)

    def save(self, *args, **kwarg):
        self.customer_number = self.get_customer_number
        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwarg)
```

Issue: When the form is submitted to create a new customer (new record) then I get the following error:

> a  'CA' 
> self  Error in formatting: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'>

When I already have a record (updating and existing Customer's info) then the code works fine. It is my understanding that it isn't able to get the `id` as it is still validating the data before being sent to the model, hence no `Customer.id` to pull for this instance.

Question: Is there a cleaner way of setting a `customer_number` that is based on the PK?

Comment: Yes if you need id, you have to save it first

Comment: @bdbd How would I code a form or a function to save and then run the def save() that I have attached to the class?